# Zoom a webview in android programmatically

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have a canvas 1000x800 inside an Android webview. When the user launches an event I'd like to center the webview into the point 300x300 and showing an zoom to show an area of 300x300 approximately. If the zoom was animated would be perfect (like when double tapping the webview in that point)

how can I do it (with javascript or with the webview calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a predefined zoom to a `WebView` using the method `setInitialScale()` method of the `WebView`-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale%28int%29

This input parameter is the percentage of zoom. You can set an initial zoom percentage and see if the required area is visible. Otherwise, you need to pan the `WebView`.